# Update statusbar from a thread using C++/CLI

Tags: multithreading, winforms, c++-cli

I'm sure this is a pretty straight forward question. I'm writing a small windows forms app using C++/CLI. When the form initializes, I start a thread that will process some code. When the code in the thread is executed, I want the thread to somehow update the text in a statusbar in the bottom of the window. So I was thinking something like this:

1. I create an event.
2. Then I create the Thread that will do some processing.
3. When the processing is done, fire an event that makes the text in the statusbar update.

Is this a reasonable way to go? If so, how do I update the statusbar from within the thread? Maybe there is a smarter way to acheive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a method like that changes the status text given a string:

```
private: void UpdateStatus(String^ msg) {
    statusBar.Text = msg;
}
```

and from the other thread, use [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(VS.80).aspx):

```
Invoke(gcnew Action<String^>(this, &Form1::UpdateStatus), "message");
```

`Invoke` will call the given delegate with the specified parameters on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, first the compiler complained about Form1:UpdateStatus not being able to acces private member of Fomr1. This was solved by changing into public: void UpdateStatus(String^ msg). However, the compiler still complains about Error C2440 and Error C3754 (both are on msdn). Any advice on this?

Comment: Did you replace `Form1` with the actual class name? Are you adding both methods in the form class itself, or somewhere else (I assumed adding these snippets to the form class itself)? I just tested this in VS2008 and it works.

Comment: I create an instance of another class from Form1. So when Form1 loads, i create an instance of Class B. In the EntryPoint of class B I perform some time-consuming operations. It goes like this: I start a thread from Form1 by creating an instance of class B called b, and do b -> Start(); When b is done with the time-consuming operations, I want to change the text in a statusBar that is a member of Form1. I hope this clarifies what I'm trying to do. And again, I'm really thankful that you are putting in your time to help me on this!

Comment: Why don't you use the `BackgroundWorker` class? It's designed to do this job: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: The BackgroundWorker did the job! I was shure there had to be an easy solution to this since it must be pretty common to do some work in the background which updates a statusbar, but I'm all new to this my knowledge was very limited. Thank you alot for your help on this!